# GHC rejects ST monad code as unable to unify type variables?

Tags: variables, haskell, types, ghc, unification

I wrote the following function:

```
(.>=.) :: Num a => STRef s a -> a -> Bool
r .>=. x = runST $ do
 v <- readSTRef r
 return $ v >= x
```

but when I tried to compile I got the following error:

```
Could not deduce (s ~ s1)
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the type signature for
             .>=. :: Num a => STRef s a -> a -> Bool
  at test.hs:(27,1)-(29,16)
  `s' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for .>=. :: Num a => STRef s a -> a -> Bool
      at test.hs:27:1
  `s1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       a type expected by the context: ST s1 Bool at test.hs:27:12
Expected type: STRef s1 a
  Actual type: STRef s a
In the first argument of `readSTRef', namely `r'
In a stmt of a 'do' expression: v <- readSTRef r
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 12):

This is exactly as intended. An `STRef` is only valid in one run of `runST`. And you try to put an external `STRef` into a new run of `runST`. That is not valid. That would allow arbitrary side-effects in pure code.

So, what you try is impossible to achieve. By design!

Answer (score 7):

You need to stay within the `ST` context:

```
(.>=.) :: Ord a => STRef s a -> a -> ST s Bool
r .>=. x = do
 v <- readSTRef r
 return $ v >= x
```

(And as hammar points out, to use `>=` you need the `Ord` typeclass, which `Num` doesn't provide.)

Comment: Note that this still won't type check, as the constraint should be `Ord`, not `Num`.